# Pick functions extension

Tags: complex-analysis

**Definition**: A Pick function $f$ is a holomorphic function on the upper half-plane $\mathbb{H}$ for which $\Im f(z)\geq 0$ for all $z\in \mathbb{H}$.

It is known that if $f$ is a Pick function, then $f(z)=\overline{f(\overline{z})}$ for $\Im z<0$.

**Definition**: For a closed set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we denote by $N_A$ the set of Pick functions $f$ for which there exists a holomorphic function $F$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus A$ such that
$$
F(z)=\begin{cases}
f(z) & \text{ } \Im z>0 \\ 
\overline{f(\overline{z})} & \text{ } \Im z<0
\end{cases}
$$

In lecture notes, the author says

> For $f\in N_A$ the extension $F$ is necessarily unique and is given for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$ by
> $$
> F(x)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(x+iy)\stackrel{(*)}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\overline{f(x+iy)}.\qquad (1)
> $$
> It follows that $F(x)$ is real for $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus A$.

Three things I need help,

1. I want to know why (*) holds,
2. I don't understand, how exactly (1) tells you that $F$ is unique, and
3. how to see that $F$ is indeed real-valued on $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$.

Comment: $1$) Looking at the definition of $F$, we know it will be holomorphic on the real line away from $A$. The limit from above is $\lim_{y \to 0^+} f(z)$ while the limit from below (which must be equal) is $\lim_{y \to 0^-} \overline{f(\bar z)} = \lim_{y \to 0^-} \overline{f(x - iy)} =  \lim_{y \to 0^+} \overline{f(x + iy)}$.

Comment: $3$) $F$ must be real valued on the real line since taking a complex conjugate is continuous, so $F(x)=\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(x+iy)\stackrel{(*)}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\overline{f(x+iy)} = \overline{\lim_{y\to 0^+}f(x+iy)} = \overline{F(x)}$

Comment: $2$) We get a unique extension by the [Schwarz Reflection Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_reflection_principle). Most graduate-level complex analysis books will have a proof of a sufficiently powerful version of this theorem.